# discord.js some reason any code under this command doesn't work?

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I've had this issue for a while now and I can't figure it out, my buy-pickaxe command works perfectly fine but any code under that does not work at all, no matter what it is. The profile.level and dl.AddLevel is just the currency they use to buy it.

Tried moving my code around and switching it a little.

```js
if(command === "buy-pickaxe") {
  if(profile.level < 15) {
    message.reply("You can't afford this item!")

  } else if(profile.level + 10 > 15) {
    var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Pickaxe");
    dl.AddLevel(message.author.id, -15)
message.member.addRole(role);
message.reply("You purchased a pickaxe!") 
  }

if(command === "buy-dagger") {
    if (profile.level < 25) {
      message.reply("You can't afford this item!")

    } else if(profile.level + 10 > 25) {
      await dl.AddLevel(message.author.id, -25)
    var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Dagger");
  message.member.addRole(role);
  message.reply("You purchased a dagger!") 
    }
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing } in  your  first if condition (or its misplaced)

it should be like this

```js
if (command === "buy-pickaxe") {
  if (profile.level < 15) {
    message.reply("You can't afford this item!")

  } else if (profile.level + 10 > 15) {
    var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Pickaxe");
    dl.AddLevel(message.author.id, -15)
    message.member.addRole(role);
    message.reply("You purchased a pickaxe!")
  }
}

if (command === "buy-dagger") {
  if (profile.level < 25) {
    message.reply("You can't afford this item!")

  } else if (profile.level + 10 > 25) {
    await dl.AddLevel(message.author.id, -25)
    var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Dagger");
    message.member.addRole(role);
    message.reply("You purchased a dagger!")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, silly mistake on my behalf!

Comment: Most IDEs have a brace highlighting feature, very handy